# Ajax Post not sending data Correctly

Tags: ajax

VB.net, MVC4, asp.net views.

**I would like to know why I cannot send or what I am doing wrong sending a parameter(int), parameter(model).**

data:

```
var ID = '<%: Model.ID%>';
var data = $('#dlg').find('form').serialize();
```

Ajax Post:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<%: Url.Action("EST", "Now")%>',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { id: ID, model: data },
  success: function (rData) {
    $('#divE').html(rData);
  }
});
```

Now - Controller:

```
<HttpPost> _
    Function EST(id As Integer, model As EViewModel) As ActionResult
```

So I'm passing a modelID and the forms data, sending them separately( with modifications ) both work, but sending them together it seems to null the 2nd parameter. Found by debugging the action.

Comment: Can you post your controller? I suspect you have a routing engine problem.

Comment: As i may have unclearly stated above, it hits the controller just fine. When i only send the int or model value(s) by themselves. ( i have altered the controller to accept only 1 or the other). But i will make an edit above here shortly that will show how I plan to accept both.

Comment: Ineed, but by default, MVC4's routing engine will only accept 1 input parameter for a controller. For what you are trying to do with multiple URI parameters, you would need to create a custom route, or put your Model ID in your Model, which I'm not really sure why you didn't do that to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use JSON.stringify.
Include contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", when you omit the contentType value default is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' this could become a trouble when you will post data

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '<%: Url.Action("EST", "Now")%>',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({ id: ID, model: data }) ,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (rData) {
        $('#divE').html(rData);
      }
    });
```